# Why won't my Frozen Synapse units obey my commands?

Tags: frozen-synapse

I'm having lots of trouble getting units to behave in *Frozen Synapse*. Sometimes they just ignore my commands.

[Here's an example](https://i.imgur.com/kpHbPCH.mp4):

<sup>(Click/tap on the GIF image below to view the higher-resolution, original video.)</sup>
[image: animated GIF showing unit not responding to waypoint orders]

I have a grenadier who currently has no orders. I'm asking him to move, but instead, he just stands there getting shot to death.

I've tried clearing focus and cancelling aim, but he still just stands there instead of following his waypoints. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Try ordering your unit to [continue on sight](http://fs.error420.com/#!/page/continue-on-sight.md) <kbd>C</kbd> or [ignore the specific enemy](http://fs.error420.com/#!/page/ignore-focus.md).

Bullet-based units (Sniper, Shotgun, Machine Gun) will attempt to shoot enemy units on sight, regardless of whether you are using the [aim command](http://fs.error420.com/#!/page/aim.md). You must explicitly order your unit to continue on sight or ignore the enemy if you want them to keep moving.